# Tower of Hanoi in Visual Prolog

Tags: prolog, towers-of-hanoi, visual-prolog

I'm fairly new to visual prolog and wondering how can I integrate the code I found on this [link](http://www.aistudy.co.kr/program/prolog/visual_prolog/Towers%20of%20Hanoi.htm).

When I create a console project in Visual Prolog the code in main.pro is:

```
/*****************************************************************************

                        Copyright (c) 2013 My Company

******************************************************************************/

implement main
    open core

clauses
    run():-
        console::init(),
        succeed(). % place your own code here
end implement main

goal
    mainExe::run(main::run).
```

So, my question is where to insert the code of tower of hanoi on this [link](http://www.aistudy.co.kr/program/prolog/visual_prolog/Towers%20of%20Hanoi.htm)?

For your convenience, here's the code:

```
/* Program ch16e05.pro */

DOMAINS
    loc =right;middle;left

PREDICATES
    hanoi(integer)
    move(integer,loc,loc,loc)
    inform(loc,loc)

CLAUSES
    hanoi(N):-
        move(N,left,middle,right).

    move(1,A,_,C):-
        inform(A,C),!.

    move(N,A,B,C):-
        N1=N-1, move(N1,A,C,B),
        inform(A,C),move(N1,B,A,C).

    inform(Loc1, Loc2):-nl,
        write("Move a disk from ", Loc1, " to ", Loc2).
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the link in your question is broken I provide a new link.
You find a PDF of the original turbo Prolog owners handbook here:

**Internet Archive, Turbo Prolog Owners Handbook 1987 (1987)**
   http://archive.org/details/bitsavers_borlandturOwnersHandbook1987_8438592

Therein is the same code with DOMAINS, PREDICATES and CLAUSES. According
to the following wikipedia entry, you can move the turbo Prolog code
almost unchanged into a visual Prolog system.

**Visual Prolog, Hanoi Example**
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Prolog#Hanoi_Example

Use 'predicates' for your public predicates in the interface of the class.
And use 'class predicates' for your private predicates in the implementation
of the class.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your code is in "modern" class based Visual Prolog, but the second part of your code is in old-style (Turbo Prolog, PDC Prolog, Visual Prolog <5.2).